# Фильтрация массива обьектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, filter

У меня есть такой обьект:

```
let INVOICE = 
 {
id: 1589387651868,
name: "testing",
data: "2020-05-03T21:00:00.000Z",
totalPrice: "40.0",
products: [
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Lemon ",
    description: "fresh",
    price: 4,
    discount: 0
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "Banana",
    description: "salat",
    price: 11,
    discount: 0
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Blueberry",
    description: "fresh",
    price: 15,
    discount: 0
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Cherry",
    description: "fresh",
    price: 10,
    discount: 0
  }
]
```

}

Такой масиив массив:

```
let PRODUCTS = [
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'Grapes',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 5
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: 'Lime',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 3
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: 'Apple',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 7
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'Lemon ',
    description: 'fresh',
    price: 4
  },
  {
    id:5,
    name: 'Cherry',
    description: 'fresh',
    price: 10
  },
  {
    id:6,
    name: 'Blueberry',
    description: 'fresh',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    id:7,
    name: 'Banana',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 11
  },{
    id:8,
    name: 'Watermelon',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 20
  },
  {
    id:9,
    name: 'Pineapple',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 30
  },
  {
    id:10,
    name: 'Orange',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 17
  },
  {
    id:11,
    name: 'Avocado',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 26
  }
];
```

Мне надо отфильтровать массив PRODUCTS по INVOICE.products в итоге должен получить новый массив PRODUCTS,
где уже не будет обьектов из массива INVOICE.products
Пытался реализовать с помощю:

```
C = A.filter(val => { B.indexOf(val) == -1;});
```

В итоге получаю пустой массив, скорей всего из-за того что обьекты в массивах разные!

Comment: а почему id у одинаковых продуктов в разных массивах разные

Comment: Исправил! Теперь нормально!

Comment: Ага, `return` вообще полезный оператор:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже если поправить id, ваш код не даст нужного результата. Можно сделать как-то так

```
ids = INVOICE.products.map(v => v.id);
C = PRODUCTS.filter(val => ! ids.includes(val.id));

console.log(C)
```

```js
let INVOICE = 
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'INVOICE 1',
    data: "2020-05-04T21:00:00.000Z",
    totalPrice: 55.8,
    products:[
      { select: 3,
        name: 'Apple',
        description: 'For eating',
        price: 30,
        discount: '6',
        id: 7
      },
      { select: 1,
        name: 'Lime',
        description: 'For a cocktail',
        price: 30,
        discount: '8',
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  }

let PRODUCTS = [
  {
    id:1,
    name: 'Grapes',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 5
  },
  {
    id:2,
    name: 'Lime',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 3
  },
  {
    id:3,
    name: 'Apple',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 7
  },
  {
    id:4,
    name: 'Lemon ',
    description: 'fresh',
    price: 4
  },
  {
    id:5,
    name: 'Cherry',
    description: 'fresh',
    price: 10
  },
  {
    id:6,
    name: 'Blueberry',
    description: 'fresh',
    price: 15
  },
  {
    id:7,
    name: 'Banana',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 11
  },{
    id:8,
    name: 'Watermelon',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 20
  },
  {
    id:9,
    name: 'Pineapple',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 30
  },
  {
    id:10,
    name: 'Orange',
    description: 'salat',
    price: 17
  },
  {
    id:11,
    name: 'Avocado',
    description: 'eating',
    price: 26
  }
];

ids = INVOICE.products.map(v => v.id);
C = PRODUCTS.filter(val => ! ids.includes(val.id));

console.log(C)
```